# Best process to make a state of ui-router from a page

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have created a working web page `page.html`, which loads `page.css` and `page.js` in the header:

```
<script src="page.js"></script>
<link href="page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Prior to that, I had already a homepage. Now, I want to create a state of homepage that leads to `subpage.html` which should have exactly the same behaviour as `page.html`:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('subpage', {
            url: '/subpage',
            templateUrl: '/subpage.html',
            ...
        });
}])
```

However, it seems that, unlike `page.html`, `subpage.html` has NO header place to load `page.css` and `page.js`.

So, what is the best way to set the fields of the `subpage` state and write `subpage.html`, from `page.html`, `page.css` and `page.js`?

Would it work if I just load `page.css` and `page.js` in the header of the `html` of the home page? There is a risk to have conflicts with existing items in the home page, no?

Comment: are you using webpack? if so you can require the css in a very modular fashion, you need a plugin for the loader but its super sweet. the js(controller) for the specific view in also specified in the router state definition. please add the code you have for page.html and that view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I realise that, in the beginning of `subpage.html`, we could load directly `js` and `css`:

```
<script src="page.js"></script>
<link href="page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

One advantage of loading in `subpage.html` rather than in homepage is that we load these files only when we need them (i.e., opening the subpage).

In terms of "conflicts" with the home page. I guess, it is more or less similar to having `js` and `css` later in the homepage or never (when we don't open the subpage).